# What function formula should I use to calculate my salary so that I don't have to differentiate between Friday and weekend manually?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, regex, google-sheets-dates

[image]

These are the formulae I am currently using where I have to manually sort out if its Friday or weekend by using conditional formatting to bring attention to the minority that needs a different formula. I have tried using `COUNTIFS` & `IF` but am unable to use it correctly.

**No. of hrs worked = Time Out - Time in - 2hrs of break**

```
=Text(C2-B2-TIME(2,0,0),"h:mm")
```

*Formula used to change no. of hrs worked to an integer where 30 minutes = 0.5*

```
=INT(C2-B2-TIME(2,0,0))*24+HOUR(C2-B2-TIME(2,0,0))+ROUND(MINUTE(C2-B2-TIME(2,0,0))/60,2)
```

**From Monday to Thursday;**

Before 6 pm, the column F will be the **no. of hrs * $10**

```
=(INT(E2-(C2-TIME(18,0,0)))*24+HOUR(E2-(C2-TIME(18,0,0)))+
 ROUND(MINUTE(E2-(C2-TIME(18,0,0)))/60,2))*10
```

After 6 pm, the column G will be the **no. of hrs till time out *$11**.

```
=(INT(C2-TIME(18,0,0))*24+HOUR(C2-TIME(18,0,0))+ROUND(MINUTE(C2-TIME(18,0,0))/60,2))*11
```

**On Friday;**

Before 6 pm, the column F will be the **no. of hrs * $10**.

```
=(INT(E4-(C4-TIME(18,0,0)))*24+HOUR(E4-(C4-TIME(18,0,0)))+
 ROUND(MINUTE(E4-(C4-TIME(18,0,0)))/60,2))*10
```

After 6 pm the column H will be the **no. of hrs till time out *$12**:

```
=(INT(C4-TIME(18,0,0))*24+HOUR(C4-TIME(18,0,0))+
 ROUND(MINUTE(C4-TIME(18,0,0))/60,2))*12
```

**Weekends**;

**No. of hrs * $12**.

```
=D5*12
```

Answer (score 1):

[image: 0]

**cell D2**:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(B2:B), TEXT(C2:C-B2:B-2/24, "h:mm")*24, ))
```

**cell E2**:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(B2:B), TEXT(C2:C-B2:B-2/24, "h:mm"), ))
```

**cell F2**:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT(WEEKDAY(A2:A,2)), "[1-5]"), 
   (INT(E2:E-(C2:C-TIME(18, 0, 0)))*24+
   HOUR(E2:E-(C2:C-TIME(18, 0, 0)))+ROUND(
 MINUTE(E2:E-(C2:C-TIME(18, 0, 0)))/60, 2))*F1, ))
```

**cell G2**:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT(WEEKDAY(A2:A, 2)), "[1-4]"), 
   (INT(C2:C-TIME(18, 0, 0))*24+
   HOUR(C2:C-TIME(18, 0, 0))+ROUND(
 MINUTE(C2:C-TIME(18, 0, 0))/60, 2))*G1, ))
```

**cell H2**:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(C2:C), IF(REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT(WEEKDAY(A2:A, 2)), "[5]"), 
   (INT(C2:C-TIME(18,0,0))*24+
   HOUR(C2:C-TIME(18,0,0))+ROUND(
 MINUTE(C2:C-TIME(18,0,0))/60,2)) * H1, 
 IF(REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT(WEEKDAY(A2:A, 2)), "[6-7]"), D2:D*H1, )), ))
```

**cell I2**:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(C2:C), F2:F+G2:G+H2:H, ))
```